# Rails two applications dependency conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines, gemfile

I have 2 rails applications - A and B. They have multiple dependencies that are incompatible to each other. Besides appliaction A is created for rails 3 and appliaction B is created for rails 4.

I would like to display content of the appliaction A, and take small part from appliaction B and embed it into rendered view. I have not found other way than merging these 2 appliacations  toegether. Unfortunately it is really complicated and can consume a lot of time.

Is there any other way to do it? I would not like to use iframes.

Comment: why not jsonp + ajax?

Comment: Basically user will operate on the content of application B. Content of A is just a dyncamically rendered layout. So I would prefer to return full response from the server.

The best solution would be to have [deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) functionallity, but the content to embed could be taken from another server.

Comment: After a little search I came to the conclusion that they are completely sepparate application stacks and they do not have a lot in common. There are two solutions:

1. Like @apneadiving said - fetch data using jsonp + ajax from 2 endpoints.
2. Merge applications together or at least extract the core part to the lib and use in the second application.